# Review of the Archetype / Trope of an Arch-Fiend

Tags: information

Sorry to see an excellent question deleted as possibly too broad. I believe this to be answerable.

What are some examples of the tropes/archetypes used in the "arch-fiend"? Specifically, an supernatural mastermind or power that would generally fill the role of as the personification, or at least leader, of all that is "evil"?

Comment: I don't know where you meant to post this, but this isn't the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Piers Anthony did an excellent job of decomposing this in 'For the Love of Evil'. This trope can be done as one of at least five of the following archetypes:

### The Judge

This archetypical take on an arch-fiend is not, specifically, out to get you. He (or she, or it) sees through our deceptions, knows what we've done wrong, sees through our lies and self-deceptions. This "evil" won't allow our dishonesty to stand and forces us either to look at the ugliness inside ourselves, or exposes us to the forces of justice. Examples: Piers Anthony's Parry, Neil Gaiman's Lucifer

### The Monster

Another popular archetype. If incorporeal, this villain is always starting mudslides, floods, earthquakes, forest fires, or inspiring the person next to you to be rude. This villain schemes for a chance to put foot soldiers on the ground. It wants little more than to see everything burn and bleed. Examples: Todd MacFarlane's Malbogian, Erik Kripke's Lucifer

### The Opponent

This arch-fiend doesn't care much about you specifically. This fiend and some nearly- or all- powerful force of good are opposed. The Opponent isn't looking to harm you, specifically, you are merely in the crossfire. To this end, you may be recruited, manipulated, tempted, or conversely attacked, undermined, and betrayed, or you may be treated neutrally, or maybe even treated well. It depends on your position as a useful lever in making other things happen to thwart the Good. Examples: Phillip Pullman's Authority

### The Tempter

This villain has a philosophy of Evil. It might be extreme liberty, fanatic darwinism (survival of the fittest), novelty for novelty's sake, art for art's sake, and so on. The villain can make a good argument for it's philosophy, and maybe is capable of seeing your weaknesses (or potential) for what it sees as virtue. The Tempter encourages you to discipline yourself to conform with it's philosophy, which to most "normal" people leaves you with a psyche that is some twisted and deformed mockery of humane. Examples: Clive Barker's Pinhead

### The Trader

This archetype sees some sort of value in you: either as a while-living servant, as a after-life servant, as some form of currency against the Good, as a power source. Whatever it is, this archetypical Evil is willing to make you a deal. You want X? The fiend is more than happy to negotiate, in exchange for what it craves out of you. Generally this is followed by recognizing the value of what it is that you bartered to the fiend in exchange for something of much lesser value. Example: Erik Kripke's Crowley, Clive Barker's Djinn

Comment: I think you mean "...at least one of the five following..."